# The best way to use filtered results multiple times in MySQL query

Tags: mysql

I have a very big Table(over 1 million records).

I want to filter this table into a given `date range` and `user_id` and search for a character in a specific field of the table.

For example, I want to get a record number with "YouTube", a number of records with "Facebook", and a number of records with "Twitter".
In other words, I need to use the table already filtered several times by the `user_id` and the `date range`.

I can do it as follows, but I think there will be a better way.

```
SELECT * FROM 
(SELECT COUNT(*) AS youtube_count FROM report
WHERE user_id = 1 AND created_at < "2023-03-01" AND service LIKE "%youtube%") AS a
INNER JOIN
(SELECT COUNT(*) AS facebook_count FROM report
WHERE user_id = 1 AND created_at < "2023-03-01" AND service LIKE "%facebook%") AS b
```

And I get the following result.

[image]

This takes some time to run because I have used the same filter several times.

I tried to create and use the Temporary Table, but because the table is very large, it takes a lot of CPU time to create the Temporary table.

Is there any shameful solution for this?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use conditional aggregation grouped by user_id :

```
SELECT 
    user_id,
    SUM(CASE WHEN service LIKE '%youtube%' THEN 1 else 0 END ) AS youtube_count,
    SUM(CASE WHEN service LIKE '%facebook%' THEN 1 else 0 END ) AS facebook_count
FROM report
WHERE user_id = 1 AND created_at < "2023-03-01"
group by user_id
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/Qp4AeF-9)

Comment: You don't need the CASE statement, just `SUM(service LIKE '%youtube%')`

Comment: don't need group by. However thank you. This is helpfull.